# I want to convert array of intensities to an image

Tags: python, csv, mnist

I have the MNIST dataset. The CSV file contains 70,000 rows and 785 columns. The last column is the label. I want to convert the first columns of a row to the respective grayscale image with dimensions 28x28.

Image of the data:

[image: data]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to convert your data from csv to grayscale?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator()
data = data_generator.flow_from_dataframe(df, color_mode="grayscale")
```

The `df` variable is your read csv. your data should return grayscale images using the code above.